# After generation iXBRL in Fujitsu XWAND unknow namespace prefix appears

Tags: java, xbrl

I'm working now on a XBRL software which uses Fujitsu XWAND for instance document generation and there are some unknown namespace prefix in file after generation.

```
<p:xbrl xmlns:iso4217="http://www.xbrl.org/2003/iso4217" xmlns:ixt="http://www.xbrl.org/inlineXBRL/transformation/2015-02-26" xmlns:ixt-sec="http://www.sec.gov/inlineXBRL/transformation/2015-08-31" xmlns:link="http://www.xbrl.org/2003/linkbase" xmlns:nonnum="http://www.xbrl.org/dtr/type/non-numeric" xmlns:num="http://www.xbrl.org/dtr/type/numeric" xmlns:p="http://www.xbrl.org/2003/instance" xmlns:us-gaap="http://fasb.org/us-gaap/2020-01-31" xmlns:utr="http://www.xbrl.org/2009/utr" xmlns:xbrldi="http://xbrl.org/2006/xbrldi" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <link:schemaRef xlink:href="igm-20201129.xsd" xlink:type="simple"/>
  <p:context id="ctx1">
    <p:entity>
      <p:identifier scheme="http://www.sec.gov/CIK">1234567890</p:identifier>
    </p:entity>
    <p:period>
      <p:startDate>2020-09-27</p:startDate>
      <p:endDate>2020-12-26</p:endDate>
    </p:period>
  </p:context>
```

There are no place in the code where this prefix (**p**) can be set and i haven't found any info in the internet about it. And moreover there are no source files of the library, so i cannot debug it and see what's going on under the hood and where this prefix come from. Prefix appears only in iXBRL generation, in standard - everything is fine.
Does anyone know anything about it?

Comment: I don't see any particular problem with the mere fact that the prefix is called "p". It is correctly assigned to the namespace `http://www.xbrl.org/2003/instance` (which is the important part: `xmlns:p="http://www.xbrl.org/2003/instance"`). The fact that most published XBRL files have no prefix (but then must have the default namespace assigned to the same namespace with: `xmlns="http://www.xbrl.org/2003/instance"`) or something like  `xbrli` does not make your example code incorrect. It seems correct to me. Only that it is XBRL, not iXBRL. Or, did I misunderstand your question?

Comment: Thanks for comment. Yeah, it's valid, but instance documents which were generated in another software don't have this prefix. That's why i thought it's wired.